# Getting a pom file in my jar created using maven clean package

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, maven-plugin

I have a spring boot application along with maven to handle dependencies.

I am creating the jar file using maven command "mvn clean package".

Jar file is getting created successfully but when i see the content of jar i get a

lib/all-1.1.2.pom in my lib folder which includes all required dependency jars.

Could you please tell what could be the possible reason i am getting it since i dont have any such dependency in my pom.xml.

Comment: Posting your pom.xml would help. Could you please add it?

Comment: Size of pom is huge cant post it here

Comment: I am using few plugins which i doubt could be the reason :

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Spring Boot, in your `pom.xml`, you should have something like :

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.5.RELEASE</version>
  </parent>
```

This is the parent of your Spring Boot application that include all the dependencies for a Spring Boot application.

Also, I suggest you see the documentation about this : http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-build-systems.html

Comment: I know. Otherwise it would not work. I meant this is why you have "hidden" dependencies.

Comment: Can you update your request and show the content of `lib/all-1.1.2.pom` ?

Comment: http://central.maven.org/maven2/com/github/fommil/netlib/all/1.1.2/all-1.1.2.pom
Link contains exact content of pom

Comment: Do you use a specific repository ?